# How to update postgresql using json sub-element

Tags: postgresql

How can I update "A" named value with 10.2 where ID equal 1003 in to a postgresql database table.

**Json Data Table**

| Id | Column |
| --- | --- |
| 1001 | {"results":[{"name":"A","value":"7.8"}, {"name":"B","value":"0.5"}]} |
| 1002 | {"results":[{"name":"B","value":"5.4"}, {"name":"D","value":"4.5"}]} |
| 1003 | {"results":[{"name":"D","value":"4.8"}, {"name":"A","value":"6.7"}]} |

**Result after update**

| Id | Column |
| --- | --- |
| 1001 | {"results":[{"name":"A","value":"7.8"}, {"name":"B","value":"0.5"}]} |
| 1002 | {"results":[{"name":"B","value":"5.4"}, {"name":"D","value":"4.5"}]} |
| **1003** | {"results":[{"name":"D","value":"4.8"}, {"name":"**A**","value":"**10.2**"}]} |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't a simple query, was able to make it with CTE only. I refer to your example table as `test`:

```
with item_in_list_pos as (
    select
        pos - 1 as pos
        from test, jsonb_array_elements(column1->'results') with ordinality a(elem, pos)
        where (
            id = 1003
            and elem->>'name' = 'A'
        )
)
update test
    set 
        column1 = jsonb_set(column1, array['results', pos, 'value']::text[], to_jsonb('10.2'::text))
    from item_in_list_pos
    where (
        id = 1003
    )
```

Comment: getting error, kindly pls go through below link

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=455e21796fd4217f4b8c11cc93b5a7a5

Comment: Sorry didn't know "Column" was `jsonb` type, need only to switch to `jsonb_array_elements`, I will update query.

Comment: All is good now.

Comment: Optimized query a little

Comment: You can add them, it is a version for your DB fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=3d3c2d24fd479b23b2ffc10ab5143d3b

Comment: value updated without quotes, I want to update the value with quotes. i.e., "10.2"

Comment: Just us `to_jsonb('10.2'::text)`

Comment: Yea i changed it already `to_jsonb('10.2'::text)`

Comment: Always forgetting about this ), if you need quotes you need to update with `text`

Comment: Enjoy it and don't forget to mark my answer as accepted ;)